# Form submission via AJAX query without allowing access to the PHP file on server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, apache

I have an ajax contact form on my page that sends data to a php file on the server (LAMP). I get flooded with spam messages that are not submitted from the website, but are sent by sending requests directly to the php file. How do I prevent that?

Comment: Use [CAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/) and/or [CSRF tokens](https://github.com/pillarjs/understanding-csrf).

Comment: Not sure how a captcha can help, whoever is doing this is firing directly to the server without surfing the website.

Comment: This is exactly what CAPTCHA is for. The server offers a challenge and the user submits a response. If the response is wrong or missing (as it would be from a direct hit that never requested the form) then you reject the submission.

Comment: Makes sense, but isn't there a way to completely prevent clients from sending requests to PHP files directly?

Comment: Nope. You could check to see that it's an AJAX request, but that's spoofable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Alex said, use captcha. Your server should ignore any requests that do not pass the captcha test. I.E. every request must read the validation from captcha in order to respond to any request. This way, you prevent bots from spamming you!